# Stata: from a bunch of duplicates, keep a particular one

Tags: duplicates, stata

In Stata, I have 3 variables: "objectid", "year", and "count". There are several duplicates in terms of "objectid" and "year". From these duplicates, I would like to keep the one with the highest value in "count".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard stuff requiring only (1) getting the observations into a `sort` order where you want is identifiable and (2) working under the aegis of `by:`. See manual entries for `by:` and/or http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004

```
bysort objectid year (count) : keep if _n == _N
```

Note that if `count` is ever missing, that value will be the one kept.